# Laravel Vue props htmlspecialchars()

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying do pass to my component data but I have still problem:

```
 htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

From backend I have array :

```
         return [
        self::DATA1 => 'data1',
        self::DATA2 => 'data2'
    ];
```

And here is my component with props:

```
    <member-edit :rate-types="{{$rateTypes}}"></member-edit>
```

I have still problem. In my component I tryed to tell prop that it is going to be Array but It doesn't work :

```
 props: {
        rateTypes: Array
    },
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to print an Array (`$rateTypes` variable) as a String in your blade template and this causes the error.

You can print the array on the blade template using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and then Vuejs can use it, like this:

```
<member-edit :rate-types="{{ json_encode($rateTypes) }}"></member-edit>
```